# Bad fonts in gmail

Tags: gmail

I'm trying ubuntu 20.04, everything is going well ... only in gmail I get bad fonts in Chrome and Chromium ... (It's ok in Firefox)

can you please advise how to fix it?

Everything is bold and some two different strange fonts.

Thank you very much.[image]